# How to pass system ENV vars to php in apache

Tags: php, docker, apache, environment-variables

I am trying to get an apache/php application to run in a container on ECS.  The app expects an ENV var named `USER_DBHOSTNAME`.  I have ECS configured to pass this into the container from an AWS Secret and make it available as an ENV var.

I can login to the running container and verify that the variable is being set in the container

```
$> echo $USER_DBHOSTNAME
$> xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx #redacted for security
```

However the php code is not seeing the variable

```php
print(getenv('USER_DBHOSTNAME');
```

outputs nothing

I know I need to add the variable to `/etc/apache2/envvars` to make this show up.  I can't figure out how to set an apache env var to be equal to the system env var.  I can set the var to a hardcoded value and it shows up

```
export USER_DBHOSTNAME=foobar
```

but when I try something like

```
export USER_DBHOSTNAME=$(echo $USER_DBHOSTNAME)
```

the var in PHP is empty.  The variable exists but it has an empty value

Comment: Have you read through https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php? It might not directly answer your question, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Did you try `apache_getenv()`?

Comment: as an aside, you don't need to put env vars in `/etc/apache2/envvars` to make them available to PHP. They just need to be available in the environment of the user. Not sure if this is true in docker but outside of docker the apache user (www-data?) is different than the normal user and therefore has a different environment

Comment: @apokryfos thank you.  I think this is actually what my problem may be.  The apache workers are being run under the `www-data` user but the ENV vars are being set on the root docker user.  I will try this.  Thanks!